# Leitura na mesma linha

Tags: c, input, scanf

Tenho uma `struct` para definir o tipo `DATA`.

```
typedef struct data {
    int ano, mes, dia;
}DATA;

DATA nasc;
```

Agora, passo a ler essas informações a partir da entrada do usuário.

```
printf("Digite sua data de nascimento");
scanf("%d", &nasc.dia);
printf("/");
scanf("%d", &nasc.mes);
printf("/");
scanf("%d", &nasc.ano);
```

Gostaria de fazer isso de uma maneira melhor. Lendo as três entradas na mesma linha e imprimindo o caracter `/` depois de cada entrada.

Como posso fazer isso?? Como continuar na mesma linha depois de um input??

Answer (score 1):

Basta fazer da seguinte forma:

```
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &nasc.dia, &nasc.mes, &nasc.ano);
```

Lembrando que o usuário precisará escrever a data utilizando as barras.

[Exemplo funcional no ideone](https://ideone.com/2Wxcd9)

Comment: Isso ajuda bastante! Mas ainda gostaria de saber se tem como inserir as barras entre as entradas... por uma questão de interface.

Answer (score 0):

Em ambiente Windows, você poderia tentar algo do tipo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct data {
   int ano, mes, dia;
}DATA;

int aux(char str[]){

   int my_number;
   str[0] = getche();
   str[1] = getche();
   my_number = atoi(str);
   return my_number;
}


int main(){

   DATA nasc;

   char str[3];
   str[2] = '\0';

   printf("Digite sua data de nascimento.\n");
   printf("  /  /\r");
   nasc.dia = aux(str);
   printf("\r%.2d/  /\b\b\b", nasc.dia);
   nasc.mes = aux(str);
   printf("\r%.2d/%.2d/", nasc.dia, nasc.mes);
   nasc.ano = aux(str);

   printf("\n\n%.2d/%.2d/%.2d", nasc.dia, nasc.mes, nasc.ano);
}
```

No Linux, as coisas são um pouco mais complicadas já que é necessário implementar um função correspondente à getche().

Caso haja interesse deixo um link para uma discussão sobre o tema: [stackoverflow.com/questions/3276546/how-to-implement-getch-function-of-c-in-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276546/how-to-implement-getch-function-of-c-in-linux)